# Swipe Gesture directions Up and Down don't work in .NET MAUI

Tags: maui, gesture-recognition, swipe-gesture

I get a really strange behavior with the swipe gesture in .NET MAUI. Directions *Up* and *Down* seem not to work, while directions *Right* and *Left* are working just fine. Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here a simple example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SwipeTester.MainPage">

        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="30,0" VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label x:Name="SwipedCounter" FontSize="18" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

            <Label HeightRequest="200"
                   WidthRequest="100"
                   BackgroundColor="Red">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Down"
                        Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_OnSwiped"
                        Threshold="20"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Up"
                        Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_OnSwiped"
                        Threshold="20"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Left"
                        Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_OnSwiped"
                        Threshold="20"/>
                    <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                        Direction="Right"
                        Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_OnSwiped"
                        Threshold="20"/>
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_OnSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        SwipedCounter.Text = count.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I tested your code, it works well on Directions Up and Down. You may need to set Threshold="50" to get it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction` property can be set to a single value from the `SwipeDirection` enumeration, or multiple values.

Swipes that occur on the horizontal axis can be recognized by setting the Direction property to `Left` and `Right`. Similarly, swipes that occur on the vertical axis can be recognized by setting the Direction property to `Up` and `Down`.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="30,0" VerticalOptions="Center"> 

    <Label x:Name="SwipedCounter" FontSize="18" HorizontalOptions="Center"
           BackgroundColor="Yellow" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100"
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

    <Label HeightRequest="200"
           WidthRequest="200"          
           BackgroundColor="Red">

        <Label.GestureRecognizers>

            <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                Direction="Down"
                Swiped="OnSwiped"
                Threshold="50" 
                />

            <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                Direction="Up"
                Swiped="OnSwiped"
                Threshold="50"
                />

            <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                Direction="Left"
                Swiped="OnSwiped"
                Threshold="50"
                />

            <SwipeGestureRecognizer
                Direction="Right"
                Swiped="OnSwiped"
                Threshold="50"
                />

        </Label.GestureRecognizers>

    </Label>

</VerticalStackLayout>
```

```cs
void OnSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e) 
{
    switch (e.Direction)
    {
        case SwipeDirection.Left:
            SwipedCounter.Text = "left";
            break;

        case SwipeDirection.Right:
            SwipedCounter.Text = "right";
            break;

        case SwipeDirection.Up:
            SwipedCounter.Text = "up";
            break;

        case SwipeDirection.Down:
            SwipedCounter.Text = "down";
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Alexandar,
thx a lot for your answer. My code now works for Up and Down swipes. But it's a little curious that I really really tried out my code several times and it didn't work for Up and Down. Then I tried the "usual suspects": updating VS, cleaning and rebuilding project, deleting the emulator and adding a new one, but Up and Down swipes still didn't work. Then I posted my question, received your answer, tried it and it worked ... not only for your threshold of 50 but as well for my original one of 20 or even 5. And I realy didn't touch the project in the mean time... somehow strange.